# Hibernate Session's get() function retrieves question marks instead of greek characters

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I have a web application that uses spring and hibernate. My hibernate session factory is configured in spring as:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.dslibweb.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The data source as:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxConnections}" />
</bean>
```

and the properties file for the data source is:

```
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=***
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.62.0.105:1433;databaseName=example;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8
jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.maxConnections=-1
```

I have a call:

```
DsActions action = (DsActions) this.hibernateCriteriaCommons.findById(id, new DsActions());
```

and findById is defined as:

```
public T findById(String id, Object model) {
    return (T) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(model.getClass(), id);
}
```

So I am calling the get method of hibernate session for a specific id and I expect an instance of type DsActions.

All works well when I run it from a local Tomcat instance (run through netbeans).

When I install it on a remote tomcat server, the instance of DsActions seems to have an encoding issue. When retriveing a field of DsActions instance I get question marks (??? ?????? ??????). The text is supposed to be greek characters

I am very confused, I do not understand why in the first case it is working and not in the second.
Note: the data is retrieved by the same database server, so no difference there. The only difference is the machine where the application is running.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If all other things are the same, then check the Tomcat config

Comment: Also you wrote "When retriveing a field of DsActions instance I get question marks (??? ?????? ??????)." You get it where? In the Tomcat log? Returned in a html by a servlet?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. When you say Tomcat config you mean the servr.xml file? I checked it and the two files are similar. The question marks I get them when I print the output in log file and when I show it on a jsp. The thing that gets me crazy is that it works on one instance of Tomcat and not on the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Hibernate retrieves that field correctly, and the problem is in the way you output these characters.

As a quick check you can add a condition such as `f.contains("?")` to your code and output its result - it should be `false` (if original string doesn't contain `?`s, of course).

For possible problems in output see [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).